# Unity Camera Rendering to Screen at Low Quality When Trying to Use Post-Processing (URP)

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, post-processing, urp

I've been having troubles with getting custom post-processing shaders to work with the 2D URP renderer, after a lot of searching I found a solution that let me use post-processing effects in 2D with URP by using camera stacking and render features. I do this by having a camera that renders most of the scene as a base camera that renders the 2D lights (the main reason I'm using URP) and a second overlay camera that renders the post-processing effect. The issue is that for some reason the quality drops a lot when I have the camera that's applying the post-processing effect enabled. Here's a couple examples:

With post-processing camera enabled
[image: With post-processing camera enabled]

With post-processing camera disabled
[image: With post-processing camera disabled]

The shader shouldn't be doing anything at the moment, but if I do make it do something like inverting the colors, the effect does get applied if I have the camera enabled. The UI has it's own camera so it's unaffected by both the low quality and the shader. I've found that disabling the render feature brings the quality back as well, but it doesn't seem to be the shader that's doing this because I can unattach the shader from the feature without disabling the feature and the low quality stays. I'm still pretty new with shaders though, so in case there is something wrong with my shader that's causing this, here's the code:

```
Shader "PixelationShader"
{
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline"}
        LOD 100
        ZWrite Off Cull Off
        Pass
        {
            Name "PixelationShader"

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"

            struct Attributes
            {
                float4 positionHCS   : POSITION;
                float2 uv           : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct Varyings
            {
                float4  positionCS  : SV_POSITION;
                float2  uv          : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            Varyings vert(Attributes input)
            {
                Varyings output;

                // Note: The pass is setup with a mesh already in clip
                // space, that's why, it's enough to just output vertex
                // positions
                output.positionCS = float4(input.positionHCS.xyz, 1.0);

                #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
                output.positionCS.y *= -1;
                #endif

                output.uv = input.uv;
                return output;
            }

            TEXTURE2D_X(_CameraOpaqueTexture);
            SAMPLER(sampler_CameraOpaqueTexture);

            half4 frag(Varyings input) : SV_Target
            {
                UNITY_SETUP_STEREO_EYE_INDEX_POST_VERTEX(input);

                float4 color = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D_X(_CameraOpaqueTexture, sampler_CameraOpaqueTexture, input.uv);
                //color.rgb = 1 - color.rgb;
                return color;
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas, thanks! Also, the editor light icons you can see in the images just started appearing in game as well, if anyone knows how to remove those or fix the white lines at the edges of the screen, that would be handy to know as well

Edit: I've noticed that the quality difference in the images I sent isn't very noticeable, but it's much more noticeable when actually playing the game

Answer (score 1):

_CameraOpaqueTexture uses bilinear downsampling by default. You can change that in the universal render pipeline asset that you use:
[dropdown under "Rendering/opaque downsampling" needs to be none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Pxe.png)

Comment: Thank you! As I said in another comment I've just decided to remove URP, so I'm unsure if this would've fixed my issue, but maybe it can help someone else

Answer (score 0):

After trying a bunch of different things, I decided to just remove URP from my project and use 3D lights on 2D sprites instead